# How to reduce write latency for cross region RDS master?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I want to build global service infrastructure on AWS.
Main Region is Seoul and also RDS Master instance will reside in Seoul region.
And global users who are using this service, they can perform *update* on this RDS's data.

In this scenario, the users can face latency issues.
Read job is distributed using `cross region read-replica`.
But write transaction can't be distributed.

For example, If users in USA updates this service, update transaction goes a long way from the USA to Korea.

Can I reduce write job latency across regions?

Comment: Unless you have a wormhole or time machine, probably not. You could go multi-master, but that creates a whole different set of complex problems.

Comment: Have you experienced a real issue, or is this just a theoretical concern? Amazon's backbone has very high bandwidth with low predictable latencies. Unless you are pushing a lot of write transactions to the database across the globe, I doubt that you will have issues. If you are experiencing an issue, publish details ...

Comment: Please consider removing either [tag:postgresql] or [tag:mysql] from the question tags unless you are actually considering both platforms.  Otherwise, they are mutually-exclusive.

Comment: If I putting on Cache layer on each global regions, It helps to improve write performance?

Comment: A caching layer will only help you with read operation performance @SookyungKim. At it's simplest, a cache is just a layer in front of the database that is faster to access (data could be temporarily stored in memory instead of on disk), and could possibly be closer to the user (i.e a cache layer set up in USA, but the master database is still in Seol). You can basically think of your db replicas as a cache layer.